# Read from CSV and store in Excel tabs

Tags: excel, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I am reading multiple CSVs (via URL) into multiple Pandas DataFrames and want to store the results of each CSV into separate excel worksheets (tabs). When I keep `writer.save()` inside the for loop, I only get the last result in a single worksheet. And when I move `writer.save()` outside the for loop, I only get the first result in a single worksheet. Both are wrong.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

work_statements = {
'sheet1': 'URL1',
'sheet2': 'URL2',
'sheet3': 'URL3'
}

for sheet, statement in work_statements.items():
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('B.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    r = requests.get(statement) # go to URL
    df = pd.read_csv(statement) # read from URL
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= sheet)
writer.save()
```

How can I get all three results in three separate worksheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are re-initializing the `writer` object with each loop. Simply initialize it once before `for` and save document once after the loop. Also, in `read_csv()` line, you should be reading in the request content, not the URL (i.e., `statement`) saved in dictionary:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('B.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for sheet, statement in work_statements.items():
    r = requests.get(statement)                  # go to URL
    df = pd.read_csv(r.content)                  # read from URL
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= sheet)
writer.save()
```